# Unable to set value to a variable in windows cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm unable to set the value of variable `foo`.The script is as follows:

```
@echo off
set foo = %1
echo %foo%
```

I'm getting this as an output:

```
ECHO is off
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the spaces surrounding your equals sign:

```
@echo off
set foo=%1
echo %foo%
```

**EDIT (to elaborate):**

You're getting `ECHO is off` because `%foo%` isn't set to anything, so the command prompt only sees `ECHO`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra spaces in `set` command:

```
set foo=%1
```

Comment: "foo " with a space is a valid variable name. You could `echo %foo %` to use it.